# Facing issues in using cancancan with authlogic in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, cancancan

```
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
```

in my gem file. I have given this in my ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(employee)
    employee ||= Employee.new
    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud
    case employee[:role]
      when 'SUPER-ADMIN'
        can :manage, :all
      when 'HR'
        can :manage, Employee
      when 'INVENTORY'
        can :manage, Inventory
        can :edit, Employee, :id => employee.id
        can :update, Employee, :id => employee.id
        can :read, Employee
      when 'EMPLOYEE'
        can :edit, Employee, :id => employee.id
        can :update, Employee, :id => employee.id
        can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

In my application controller I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_employee_session, :current_employee
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "You are not authorize to access this page"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  load_and_authorize_resource
  private

  def require_employee
    unless current_employee
      redirect_to new_employee_session_url, notice: I18n.t('require_employee')
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Now when go through change password link if I am login with Employee then it does not allow me to change password and if i am not login and go through the forgot password than also it wont allow me. I had given this in my password_resets_controller.rb

```
 class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_employee, :only => [:edit, :update]
  skip_authorize_resource 
  def new
  end

  def create        
    @employee =  Employee.where(email: employee_params['email']).first
    if @employee
      @employee.password = generate_activation_password(8)
      @employee.password_confirmation = @employee.password
      if @employee.save
        current_employee_session.destroy

        redirect_to new_employee_session_path, notice: I18n.t('password_created')
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = I18n.t('email_exists')
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path
    end

  end

  def edit
    @employee = current_employee
  end

  def update
    @employee = Employee.find(current_employee.id)
    if @employee.update(employee_params)
      current_employee_session.destroy
      redirect_to new_employee_session_path, notice: I18n.t('updated_password')
    else
      flash[:error] = I18n.t('invalid_password')
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

and am getting this error

[image]

```
NameError (uninitialized constant PasswordReset):
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:151:in `resource_class'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:122:in `adapter'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:116:in `find_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/cancancan-1.10.1/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `instance_exec'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block in make_lambda'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
```

Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your `require_employee` method and password reset controller's edit and update action.

Comment: modified question please go through it

Comment: I have added the answer please check and revert back if you face any issues.

Comment: i have updated the answer please check

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Plaese try this I hope this will help.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  prepend_before_filter :set_action_and_controller

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_employee_session, :current_employee
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "You are not authorize to access this page"
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  load_and_authorize_resource if set_action_and_controller

  def set_action_and_controller
    if params[:controller] == "password_resets"
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

  helper_method :set_action_and_controller

  private

  def require_employee
    unless current_employee
      redirect_to new_employee_session_url, notice: I18n.t('require_employee')
      return false
    end
  end    
end
```

**password_resets_controller.rb**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_employee, :only => [:edit, :update]
  authorize_resource :class => false #Or skip_authorize_resource :class => false
  skip_authorize_resource
  ....
end
```

Comment: `NameError (uninitialized constant Ability::PasswordReset):` it gives me this error

Comment: I think PasswordReset is not a model therefore it will not here in ability.rb

Comment: @dinshawraje I have edited my answer please try to run the code.

Comment: can you please comment out this for a while `load_and_authorize_resource` in application controller and try?

Comment: It is working when I comment out this but I don't want to write `load_and_authorize_resource` in each every controller thats why I had written it in application controller

Comment: `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `params' for ApplicationController:Class):`

Comment: this is also not working  I am trying to solve this issue since last 4 days and am not getting it how to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79541/discussion-between-dinshaw-raje-and-amit-sharma).

Comment: @dinshawraje, have you tried to run the code with my updated answer?

Comment: yes I have tried it with your latest code also but my error remaains same I dont why its happening

Comment: Which error you are getting now `NameError (uninitialized constant Ability::PasswordReset)` or `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method params`

Comment: @dinshawraje, I have changed the `before_filter` with `prepend_before_filter` so please try it out now

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: can you please write this `puts "#{params.inspect}"` on the top in `set_action_and_controller` method and check wheather the Params are getting printed in log before error occurs, also post the printed value.